"How to Resolve `punycode` Deprecation Warning When Deploying Next.js Project?"
I'm trying to deploy my Next.js project to [Hosting Service] and I’m encountering a deprecation warning related to the punycode module. The warning message is:
This warning appears during the deployment process and I’m unsure how to resolve it.

Node.js Version: 22.5.1
Next.js Version: 14.2.4
Hosting Platform: firebase

i got this error - (node:11832) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
